# More compact way of checking multiple isValid statements

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have a number of methods where I perform validation - tryParse being one of the main functions i use.

I end up with code like this:

```
bool isValid = true;

int dealId;
isValid = !int.TryParse(strArr[0], out dealId) ? false : isValid;

DateTime createdOn;
isValid = !DateTime.TryParse(strArr[1], out createdOn) ? false : isValid;

isValid = !tmp.Add(new BookmarkedDeal(userId, dealId, createdOn)) ? false : isValid;
```

Is there a better way of setting isValid to false only if the result is false?

Comment: Is this 3 separate methods?  Or is `IsValid` true only when all 3 conditions are `true`?

Comment: If the first TryParse fails, why do you carry on trying to validate? Why not just return false as soon as it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what you definition of "better" is, but you can do something like this:

```
int dealId;
DateTime createdOn;

return int.TryParse(strArr[0], out dealId) &&
       DateTime.TryParse(strArr[1], out createdOn) && 
       tmp.Add(new BookmarkedDeal(userId, dealId, createdOn))
```

(assuming of course you are returning this from a method, otherwise, you can just set the value of this to a `bool isValid` and use it as you did before)

`&&` is called the conditional-AND operator.  The basic idea is it will only evaluate far enough to see if the returned value will satisfy the condition(s).  So first it will check to see if `int.TryParse()` returns a true, if it does, it will check `DateTime.TryParse()` and then the following method if it returns true.  The beauty of this operator is if any fails, then it knows that it cannot possibly be true and returns a false immediately.

(There is also a conditional-OR operator (`||`) that acts the same way, but if evaluates only fair enough until it hits a `true`, hence making the entire expression true).

Answer (score 1):

### Short-Circuited Evaluation:

```
int dealId;
DateTime createdOn;

bool isValid = int.TryParse(strArr[0], out dealId)
               &&
               DateTime.TryParse(strArr[1], out createdOn)
               &&
               tmp.Add(new BookmarkedDeal(userId, dealId, createdOn));
```

(in the above the statement will short-circuit i.e. stop being evaluated as soon as a term evaluates to false)

In addition you could order the validation so that the thing most likely to fail comes first...then you can perform the validation quicker, by not exploring the other paths. (a nice example of premature optimization...but if each term could take a while to execute, then worth bearing in mind).

================================================================================

Two alternative ways of doing it, which evaluates each term and records isValid=false if any of the evaluations are false.

### Using the Logical AND (&&):

(it's important to put the "&& isValid" on right side of the expression to avoid short-circuiting when the previous isValid is false).

```
int dealId;
DateTime createdOn;

bool isValid = int.TryParse(strArr[0], out dealId);
isValid = DateTime.TryParse(strArr[1], out createdOn) && isValid;
isValid = tmp.Add(new BookmarkedDeal(userId, dealId, createdOn)) && isValid;
```

### Using the Bitwise AND (&):

```
int dealId;
DateTime createdOn;

bool isValid = int.TryParse(strArr[0], out dealId)
               &
               DateTime.TryParse(strArr[1], out createdOn)
               &
               tmp.Add(new BookmarkedDeal(userId, dealId, createdOn));
```

Comment: If you want a non-short circuiting AND just use `&` rather than `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
int dealId;
DateTime createdOn;
bool isValid = int.TryParse(strArr[0], out dealId) && 
     DateTime.TryParse(strArr[1], out createdOn) && 
     tmp.Add(new BookmarkedDeal(userId, dealId, createdOn)
```

As && is executed from left to right, the variables which is retrieved from previous call will be ready for next call.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way you could approach.  I'm not sure what the overhead of passing out params costs the system, so why not just catch it if it errors?

```
bool isValid;
try
{ 
   int dealID = int.Parse(strArr[0]);
   DateTime createdOn = DateTime.Parse(strArry[1]);
   tmp.Add(new BookmarkedDeal(userId, dealId, createdOn);
   isValid = true;
}
catch
{
   isValid = false;
}
```

Comment: You could also go with not declaring a bool for the check doing it this way: you could see if the `Count` of your tmp collection has changed.  Otherwise if its a function, just use a `return true` or `return false`